When I am start my laptop it's showing failed to start gdm.service and plymouth-quit.service
I tried everything with the help of ChatGPT, but I still can't do anything. I tried many things, but still I didn't get anything done.

Your problem details are somewhat lacking as the above comments reports, however, take a look at the following link and see if the suggested fix might work for you. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=273302 & https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=248125
